# Ignore everything in a directory except one subfolder

Tags: regex, regular-language, unison

I have a directory `~/x7/music/sfx`.
There are some files and folders in the root of `~/x7/music`.
I need to sync only the `sfx` folder and ignore anything else in `music`.

I've tried many variants, but all of them was wrong.

```sh
ignore = Name music/*
ignorenot = Regex music/sfx/.* (OR just *)
```

does not work.

I was expecting to use something like

```sh
ignore = Name music/*^/
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with unison, but to ignore everything except sfx you could use

```
ignore = Regex /root/path/to/music/.*
ignorenot Regex /root/path/to/music/sfx/.*
```

[Documentation Source](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#ignore)

> There is also an `ignorenot` preference, which specifies a set of
>   patterns for paths that should not be ignored, even if they match an
>   ignore pattern. However, the interaction of these two sets of patterns
>   can be a little tricky. Here is exactly how it works:
>
> - Unison starts detecting updates from the root of the replicas—i.e., from the empty path. If the empty path matches an `ignore` pattern and
>     does not match an `ignorenot` pattern, then the whole replica will be
>     ignored. (For this reason, it is not a good idea to include `Name *`
>     as an `ignore` pattern. If you want to ignore everything except a
>     certain set of files, use `Name ?*.`)
> - If the root is a directory, Unison continues looking for updates in all the immediate children of the root. Again, if the name of some
>     child matches an `ignore` pattern and does not match an `ignorenot`
>     pattern, then this whole path including everything below it will be
>     ignored.
> - If any of the non-ignored children are directories, then the process continues recursively.

Comment: unfortunately, your solution is not working properly. It still syncing all music folder.
I cannot sync only this folder, because unison support 2 sources (in example remote and local) so i can use only regex for this specific operation.

Comment: i looked at their docs, where they explain how to do this, and updated my answer

Comment: _Thank you for trying to help)_  

This string:  
`ignore = Regex /home/det/x7/music/((?!sfx).)*`  or (~./x7/music...)
 tells **error**:  
`Fatal error: File "x7", line 33: Malformed pattern "Regex /home/det/x7/music/((?!sfx).)*".`

Comment: Updated to use ignorenot

Answer (score 1):

Following unison's documentation, if a certain path is ignored then so does *everything bellow it*. So, if you want to ignore everything within a folder except a subfolder, you should not ignore the folder itself, but everything inside it (which is different), and then use `ignorenot`.

```
ignore = Path x7/music/?*
ignore = Path x7/music/.?*
ignorenot = Path x7/music/sfx
```

That should do it.

Regarding the particular regexs used there, I'm following once again unison's documentation advice: "For this reason, it is not a good idea to include `Name *` as an ignore pattern. If you want to ignore everything except a certain set of files, use `Name ?*`."
The second `ignore` line ignores also hidden files/folders within `music`, if that's necessary for you.

Answer (score 0):

On 2.48.3, this should work:

```
ignore = Path /root/path/to/music/*
ignorenot = Path /root/path/to/music/sfx
```